# Java; Jframe not repainting

Tags: java, timer, jframe, actionlistener, repaint

I'm trying to create a circle around the mouse constantly in a JFrame, i.e the circle follows the mouse around the screen. To do this, I'm trying to use repaint() coupled with a timer, so that the circle continuously updates its location. For now, I have the program repainting the circle every second.

```
class MouseJFrame  extends JFrame implements MouseListener{
    int circleXcenter;
    int circleYcenter;
    int circleRadius = 25;
    boolean show = false;
    int delay = 1000; 

// listen for and respond to mouse events
    public MouseJFrame(){
        new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

// paints a circle
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        if(show){
          g.drawOval(circleXcenter,circleYcenter,
                            circleRadius*2,circleRadius*2);
        }
    }

// getX and getY return the location of the mouse
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
      int xLocation = e.getX();
      int yLocation = e.getY();
      show = true;
      circleXcenter = xLocation-circleRadius;
      circleYcenter = yLocation-circleRadius;
      repaint();
   }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
      int xLocation = e.getX();
      int yLocation = e.getY();
      show = true;
      circleXcenter = xLocation-circleRadius;
      circleYcenter = yLocation-circleRadius;
      repaint();
    }
    };                                                


// class to create MouseJFrame object
public class TestMouseJFrame{

    public static void main(String[] a){
       MouseJFrame  myMouseJFrame = new MouseJFrame ();
       myMouseJFrame.setSize(200, 200);
       myMouseJFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

However, I get an error message regarding the ActionListener. When I try to fix this I get a load of other errors. 
What can I do to get my program to run as intended?

Comment: You're more likely to get answers if you include the error messages you are getting from this code.